# Minimum Probability of Intersection of 3 events theory

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization, conditional-probability

Say you have $P(A) = P(B) = P(C) = 0.9$, but they are not necessarily independent events.

**What is the minimum probability of $P(A ∩ B ∩ C)$?**

For example, we know that
$P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B) \leq 1$, so
$P(A ∩ B) \geq P(A) + P(B) - 1 = 0.9 + 0.9 -1 = 0.8$
So the min probability of $P(A ∩ B)$ is $0.8$

I can only find the maximum probability being $0.8$ because
$P(A ∩ B ∩ C) \leq P(A ∩ B), P(B ∩ C), P(A ∩ C) = 0.8$

The working I've done so far:
$0 \leq P(A ∪ B ∪  C) \leq1$
$0 \leq P(A) + P(B) +P(C) - P(A ∩ B) - P(A ∩ C) - P(B ∩ C) + P(A∩B∩C) \leq 1$
$-2.7 \leq P(A ∩ B ∩ C) - P(A ∩ B) -  P(A ∩ C) -  P(B ∩ C) \leq -1.7$
$1.7 \leq P(A ∩ B) +  P(A ∩ C) + P(B ∩ C) - P(A ∩ B ∩ C) \leq 2.7$

$P(A ∩ B ∩ C) + 2.7 \geq P(A ∩ B) +  P(A ∩ C) + P(B ∩ C)$
$P(A ∩ B ∩ C) \geq P(A ∩ B) +  P(A ∩ C) + P(B ∩ C) - 2.7$

Since, $0.8\leq P(A ∩ B)\leq 0.9$
$2.4 \leq P(A ∩ B) +  P(A ∩ C) + P(B ∩ C) \leq 2.7$

So $P(A ∩ B ∩ C) >= 2.4 - 2.7$? or $2.7 - 2.7$? Which is just $0$?

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! Please have a look at the [LaTeX guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for suggestions on how to improve the mathematical typesetting in your post -- right now, your question is quite hard to read and follow.

Comment: No probability can be over $1$. It may be useful to think about your problem in familiar everyday terms, before trying to do it symbolically. Suppose that $A$ is "has a dog", $B$ is "has a cat", and $C$ is "eats steak for breakfast". So let's say nine out of ten people have a dog, nine out of ten people have a cat, and nine out of ten people eat steak for breakfast. List out ten people, and for each of the three properties, assign it to nine of them (not necessarily the same nine). What is the fewest number of people you think you can make have all three?

Comment: You can express the problem as a linear programming problem.

Comment: @BrianTung: I agree with you that this particular problem can be solved with a modicum of commonsense, without the use of heavy artillery.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via linear programming, with a nonnegative decision variable $p_S$ for each of the possible subsets $S$ and linear constraints to enforce the given probabilities.  For your example, the problem is to minimize $p_{111}$ subject to
\begin{align}
p_{001} + p_{011} + p_{101} + p_{111} &= 0.9 \\
p_{010} + p_{011} + p_{110} + p_{111} &= 0.9 \\
p_{100} + p_{101} + p_{110} + p_{111} &= 0.9 \\
p_{000} + p_{001} + p_{010} + p_{011} + p_{100} + p_{101} + p_{110} + p_{111} &= 1 
\end{align}
The minimum objective value turns out to be $0.7$, attained by $p_{011}=p_{101}=p_{110}=0.1$, $p_{111}=0.7$, and all other $p_S = 0$.

The maximum objective value turns out to be $0.9$, attained by $p_{000}=0.1$, $p_{111}=0.9$, and all other $p_S = 0$.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned "nonnegative" in the definition of the variables.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved very simply using what I call a "line diagram"

$A: 0\,0\,|0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0|\bullet\quad$ Fill 9/10 of sample space from left end
$B: \bullet\,0\,|0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,|0\quad$ Fill 9/10 of sample space from other end
$C: 0\bullet|0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0\,0|0\quad$ Fill 9/10 of sample space so as to minimize $A\cap B\cap C$

Ans $= 0.7$

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be expressed as an LP and solved using symmetry.

Suppose $f$ is convex and $P$ is some permutation such that $f(Px) = f(x)$ and, if $x$ is feasible, then $Px$ is feasible. Then since $f$ is convex, we see that
$f({1 \over n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} P^k x) \le f(x)$. In particular, if $x$ is optimal, then so is the 'average'
${1 \over n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} P^k x$.
[image]
Choose $P$ to be the 'rotation' indicated in the diagram. We see that the problem can be reduced to three non negative variables $x$ for $x_{A \bar{B} \bar{C}}$, $y$ for $x_{A {B} \bar{C}}$ and $z$ for $x_{A BC}$ that satisfy
$x+2y+z = 0.9$, $3x+3y+z \le 1$.

Subtracting gives
$2x+y \le 0.1$, and since $z=0.9-2y-x$ we get
$z \ge 0.7+x$ and hence $0.7$ is a lower bound.
Setting $x=0$ gives $y=0.1$ which is feasible so
we see that $z=0.7$ is attained.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

We can also find the answer using the ***Venn Diagram***.

---

Let the probability of only $1$ regions be denoted by $I$ which would be $a+b+c$, 
Let $II$ denote only $2$ regions, i.e., $w+x+y$ and 
Let $III$ denote only $3$ region, i.e., $z$.

---

Now we know that since $P(\text{Universe})=1$, so: $$\Rightarrow I+II+III+n=1$$ where $n$ represents the region outside the venn diagram, that is, belonging to none of $A$ or $B$ or $C$.

Since $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=0.9$, so: $$I+2II+3III=2.7$$

Now, subtracting (1) from (2), we get:
$$II+2III=1.7+n$$

---

Now the last equation, eq (3) will help us get our answer as follows:
**To minimize**, let $n=0$
Then let $II=k$ and so from eq(1) we have $III=1-k$ assuming $I=0$. 
Now substituting in eq(3):
$$k+2(1-k)=1.7$$
$$\Rightarrow k=0.3$$
Thus, the $\boxed{\text{minimum value of }III=0.7}$.

---

**To maximise** $III$, the we would have let $n=k$ and assumed that both $I=II=0$ to get from eq(1) that $III=1-k$. 
Now substituting in eq(3):
$$2(1-k)=1.7+k$$
$$\Rightarrow k=0.1$$
Thus, the $\boxed{\text{maximum value of }III=0.9}$.